# Is it possible to enable FIPS on Debian 8?

Tags: debian-jessie, fips-140-2

Is it possible to enable FIPS on Debian 8?

After googling extensively I could not any reference on how to enable FIPS in Debian 8, which leads me to believe it is not possible.

Comment: What environment are you operating in where this compliance is useful to you? Which FIPS standard do you wish to achieve, to what level? How exactly do you plan to stay compliant on an end of life operating system?

Comment: The standard needed is FIPS 140-2. 
I am well aware that Debian 8 support is past the end-of-life, but right now I am just interested in finding whether there is a set of steps that would allow me to enable FIPS on a Debian 8 server (like Centos 7), or a PPA containing FIPS compliant packages (like Ubuntu 16/18).